# probe is marked non-null but is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, illegalstateexception

I'm able to insert data in my table but getting error in findAll api at return statement .

I'm also not able to debug my project. After debugging `throw new IllegalArgumentException("null KeyStore name");` exception like in img

[image]

```
@RestController
     @CrossOrigin
     @RequestMapping("/queryconditionapi")
     public class QueryConditionController {
        
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Autowired
        QueryConditionService   queryConditionService; 
        
          
          
          @RequestMapping(value = "/allConditions", produces = "application/json", method = 
             RequestMethod.POST)
             public BaseResponse findAll(@RequestParam Integer page, @RequestParam Integer numberofRecords,
                        @RequestBody QueryConditionRequest queryConditionRequest,@RequestParam Boolean pagination) {
    
  return queryConditionService.getAll(page, numberofRecords, queryConditionRequest, pagination) ;   
                }
          }
```

this is the error I got after I hit findAll API

in text form

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: probe is marked non-null but is null
at org.springframework.data.domain.TypedExample.<init>(TypedExample.java:33)
at org.springframework.data.domain.Example.of(Example.java:39)
at com.equaze.service.impl.BaseServiceImpl.getAllData(BaseServiceImpl.java:170)
at com.equaze.service.impl.BaseServiceImpl.getAll(BaseServiceImpl.java:148)
at com.equaze.controller.QueryConditionController.findAll(QueryConditionController.java:46)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.equaze.config.MyCORSFilter.doFilter(MyCORSFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
```

Comment: can you post the error logs as text instead of images? It is really not easy to look that images and code at the same time.

Comment: I edited the error in text form pls help

Comment: One possible issue is that you are passing the keystorename null. Check where it is coming from and probably debug at that point